# variables when javascript function is used as the basis for a object -

Tags: javascript, function, object

What is the advantage of using "this.name" rather than "name" in when a javascript function is used as the basis for a object -

```
function cat(name) {    
    this.name = name;
    this.talk = function() {
        alert( this.name + " says meeow!" )
        alert( name  + " says meeow!" )
    }
} 

cat1 = new cat("Sylvester")
cat1.talk()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point of using `this.variable` rather than `variable` is so that you can reference the variable outside of the scope of the constructor without polluting the global namespace.

In your example, the `talk` function is added in the constructor. For a more object-oriented approach to JavaScript, the `talk` function would normally be defined on `Cat`s `prototype`:

```
function Cat(name) {
    this.name = name;
}
Cat.prototype = {
    talk: function () {
        alert(this.name + ' says meeow!');
    }
};
```

Notice how the function is not set in the constructor? The talk function would have no reference to `name` beyond the calling object.

Additionally, after instantiating the `Cat` object, a user could override the value by accessing the property directly:

```
var a = new Cat('bob');
a.talk(); //'Bob says meeow!'
a.name = 'Joe';
a.talk(); //'Joe says meeow!'
```

Using `this` is also important if you plan on calling a function in different object contexts:

```
function foo(bar) {
    this.baz = bar;
}

foo('fizz'); //sets window.baz === 'fizz'

var a = {};
foo.call(a, 'buzz'); //sets a.baz === 'buzz'
```

---

If you *don't* want the value to be externally editable after the constructor call, by all means, declare the function in the constructor scope to encapsulate the value and prevent further modification.

Comment: Great answer. It might also be worth noting, given the appropriate scenario for choosing `variable` instead of `this.variable`, `variable` performs slightly faster. [Here's](http://jsperf.com/object-property-vs-constructor-parameter-retrieval) the trivial jsperf.

Comment: @swaggler, premature optimization is the root of all evil etc...your test doesn't take into account memory usage for the number of instances. If you create one million instances of `Cat` using a `talk` function defined in the constructor, you'll have one million different functions that need to be stored in memory. If you store the `talk` function on the prototype, only one instance ever need exist.

Comment: Ah, okay. Apologies for bad testing.

Comment: @swaggler, i'm not saying the testing was bad, i'm just saying you need to test in the context of the application.

Comment: Would you mind demonstrating a test more conducive to learning something from this example? Or is a test unsuitable here?

Comment: @swaggler, the difference in performance is so minor that it shouldn't be necessary to test unless you're running into significant issues in an application. As I said in my answer, in one situation the variables are accessible publicly, and in the other, they're not. Using the right tool for the job should be encouraged over worrying about minor performance gains, unless performance is provably an issue. So much of JavaScript is asynchronous that developers can get away with murder as far as performance is concerned, most cycles will be in wait for the user anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Try reading this:

http://www.quirksmode.org/js/this.html

basically when you use the "this" keyword, you are referenving a variable that is specific to whatever "this" is, which in the case of your example is an cat object.

for example, if you have a javascript variable named color, and you have a cat object that has a color variable, if you want to referrence the color variable within the scope of a specific object, you would use this.color, instead of color.

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the name!

```
cat1 = new cat("Sylvester");
cat1.name = 'Tom';
cat1.talk();​​
```

`name` is still `"Sylvester"`

`this.name` is now `"Tom"`